# pandas_profiling.ProfileReport error: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe called combined. I take a subset of this dataframe, call it A. When I do Profilereport on combined, there is no problem. When I do the report for A I get the above mentioned error. Here the code:

```
A = combined.loc[combined.xy== False]
pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(A) #this gives me the error
pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(combined.loc[combined.xy== False]) #same error
pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(combined) # no error
```

Here is the error:

```
    C:\Users\xy\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\report.py:60: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in longlong_scalars
  width = int(freq / max_freq * 99) + 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-bf3aa50b97ad> in <module>()
----> 1 pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(A)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\__init__.py in __init__(self, df, **kwargs)
     67 
     68         self.html = to_html(sample,
---> 69                             description_set)
     70 
     71         self.description_set = description_set

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\report.py in to_html(sample, stats_object)
    172                                                        templates.template('freq_table'), templates.template('freq_table_row'), 10)
    173             formatted_values['firstn_expanded'] = extreme_obs_table(stats_object['freq'][idx], templates.template('freq_table'), templates.template('freq_table_row'), 5, n_obs, ascending = True)
--> 174             formatted_values['lastn_expanded'] = extreme_obs_table(stats_object['freq'][idx], templates.template('freq_table'), templates.template('freq_table_row'), 5, n_obs, ascending = False)
    175 
    176         rows_html += templates.row_templates_dict[row['type']].render(values=formatted_values, row_classes=row_classes)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\report.py in extreme_obs_table(freqtable, table_template, row_template, number_to_print, n, ascending)
    123 
    124         for label, freq in six.iteritems(obs_to_print):
--> 125             freq_rows_html += _format_row(freq, label, max_freq, row_template, n)
    126 
    127         return table_template.render(rows=freq_rows_html)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\report.py in _format_row(freq, label, max_freq, row_template, n, extra_class)
     58 
     59     def _format_row(freq, label, max_freq, row_template, n, extra_class=''):
---> 60             width = int(freq / max_freq * 99) + 1
     61             if width > 20:
     62                 label_in_bar = freq

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following function:

```
for c in DB:
print(c)
print(DB[c].dtypes)
if DB[c].dtypes != bool and DB[c].dtypes != np.float64 and DB[c].dtypes != np.uint64 and DB[c].dtypes != np.uint64 and DB[c].dtypes != np.uint8 and DB[c].dtypes != np.datetime64 and DB[c].dtypes != np.timedelta64 and DB[c].dtypes != np.dtype('<m8[ns]'):
    DB[c] = DB[c].astype("str")
    DB[c] = DB[c].astype("category")

elif DB[c].dtypes == bool:
    DB[c] = DB[c].astype("int")
```

This converts every datatype except bool, dates and several typed of numbers to string, and then to category. It has to be first to string and then to category, else the error will remain.